# Using Arrays library to merge sort an int array

Tags: java, mergesort

I want to use the function

```
public static void sort(Object[] a)
```

To sort an int array but I am not sure how to do it so that I know definitely sure that it is using the merge sort and not any other sort.

Here is the Java documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

And below is what I think would be a correct implementation of the function in order to use the merge sort.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     int arr[] = { 3, 2, 4, 1, 99, 30, 5, 3 };
     Arrays.sort(arr);
 }
```

Would this be correct? And further I wanted to specify an index from where to start sorting etc with

```
sort(Object[] a, int fromIndex, int toIndex)
```

How would I make sure to write up the code so that it used the merge sort and not quick sort.

Comment: The method you want to use expects an array of Objects. An int[] is an array of ints, not an array of Objects. Why do you care whether the algorithm is a merge sort or a quicksort?

Comment: @JBNizet I need to bench mark my own implementation of an algorithm with that of the java inbuilt ones

Comment: Then don't call Arrays.sort(int[]), since it uses a quicksort, and not a merge sort. Note that writing a correct benchmark in Java is a very complex task. If you don't know the difference between an int and an Object yet, you should probably concentrate on something other than writing benchmarks. Learn the basics first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays.sort method normally uses Quick Sort for arrays of primitives and Merge Sort for arrays of objects.

Therefore, in order to use Merge Sort, I guess you have to declare your array as an Integer object array, e.g.

```
// Unsorted array
Integer[] a = { 2, 6, 3, 5, 1 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Arrays.sort uses both! It seems like, for your integer implementation it uses quicksort.

https://cafe.elharo.com/programming/java-programming/why-java-util-arrays-uses-two-sorting-algorithms/

Comment: How might I go about making it so that it only uses merge sort then? While still using arrays; and not collections etc.

Comment: Try using Integer object instead of int! You can also create your own class that implements Comparable, it should ensure merge sort from Arrays.sort

Answer (score 0):

There is a legacy Merge Sort implementation in Arrays utility class encapsulated inside `LegacyMergeSort` class.

As mentioned by-default Arrays.sort will not use it. So you need to instruct the jvm to use it. This is as per the Java docs:

> ```
>   Old merge sort implementation can be selected (for
>   compatibility with broken comparators) using a system property.
> ```

The system property is `java.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true` and you can set it either using `java -Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true jar` or using `System.setProperty("java.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort",true);`